# Spring Data: Unique field in MongoDB document

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

let's say I have the following database entity:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private String id;

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private String email; 

}
```

How can I enforce the field email to be unique? That means MongoDB should check if a user record with this email address already exists when the application tries to save the entity.

Comment: @Indexed(unique = true)

Comment: So it only works in combination with @Indexed?

Comment: I found this stackoverflow question/answer which helped me on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62217147/845117 (None of the answers here helped me; running Springboot 3.0.2, Mongo)

Answer (score 22):

Mongodb needs to create and index a field in order to know whether the field is unique or not.

```
@Indexed(unique=true)
private String email;
```

Comment: I tried this and the mongo driver didn't do any enforcing to make this unique

Comment: @David :  Did you create index on mongo side as well?

Answer (score 9):

First, use `Indexed` annotation above of your field in your model as shown below:

```
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String email;
```

Also, you should programmatically define your index. You should use the below code when defining your `MongoTemplate`.

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps("YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME").ensureIndex(new Index("YOUR_FEILD_OF_COLLECTION", Direction.ASC).unique());
```

For your case, you should use:

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps("users").ensureIndex(new Index("email", Direction.ASC).unique());
```

Comment: Why do we need to use the annotation if all the work is done on `mongoTemplate`?

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me, but you have to delete your database and then re-run your application

```
 spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true
```

Comment: @Moumen- How possible without deleting the database?

Answer (score 6):

As of Spring Data MongoDB 3.0, automatic index creation is turned off by default. So basically, besides using `@Indexed`, you have to configure default indexing options. What you need to do is to make `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true` in the `application.properties` file, and then `@Indexed` will work like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the below solutions, it worked for me.

Note: Please delete your db before you re-try with the below solutions.

Solution - 1

```
@Indexed(unique = true, background = true)
private String emailId;
```

Solution - 2

Add `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true` to your application.properties file.

or

Add `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation:true` to your yaml file

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a custom Mongo configuration -> spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation:true won't work. Instead try adding this to your MongoConfig:

```
       @Override
       public boolean autoIndexCreation() {
       return true;
       }
```

It solved the problem for me....