# Spring Boot 2.3.0 - MongoDB Library does not create indexes automatically

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

I've provided a sample project to elucidate this problem: https://github.com/nmarquesantos/spring-mongodb-reactive-indexes

According to the spring mongo db documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage):

`the @Indexed annotation tells the mapping framework to call createIndex(…) on that property of your document, making searches faster. Automatic index creation is only done for types annotated with @Document.`

In my Player class, we can observe the both the @Document and @Indexed annotation:

```
@Document
public class Player {

@Id
private String id;

private String playerName;

@Indexed(name = "player_nickname_index", unique = true)
private String nickname;


public Player(String playerName, String nickname) {
    this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    this.playerName = playerName;
    this.nickname = nickname;
}

public String getPlayerName() {
    return playerName;
}

public void setPlayerName(String playerName) {
    this.playerName = playerName;
}

public String getNickname() {
    return nickname;
}

public void setNickname(String nickname) {
    this.nickname = nickname;
}
}`
```

And in my application class, i'm inserting oneelement to check the database is populated successfully:

```
@PostConstruct
public void seedData() {
    var player = new Player("Cristiano Ronaldo", "CR7");

    playerRepository.save(player).subscribe();

}
```

If I check MongoDb after running my application, I can see the collection and the element created successfully.

The unique index for nickname is not created. I can only see an index created for the @Id attribute. Am I missing anything? Did I mis-interpret the documentation?

Comment: did you try to set index name? `@Indexed(name = "nick_name_index")`. Also did you try to save duplicates to test index?

Comment: yep duplicates are saved and yes I have tried with name, no difference.

same issues.

everytime I restart the app, a new entry is added with the same values.

Comment: I've updated my sample with a name added to the index.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The Spring Data MongoDB version come with Spring Boot 2.3.0.RELEASE is 3.0.0.RELEASE. Since Spring Data MongoDB 3.0, [the auto-index creation is disabled by default.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#new-features.3.0)

To enable auto-index creation, set `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation = true` or if you have custom Mongo configuration, [override the method `autoIndexCreation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.index-creation)

```java
@Configuration
public class CustomMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

  @Override
  public boolean autoIndexCreation() {
    return true;
  }

  // your other configuration
}
```

Comment: Extending `AbstractMongoClientConfiguration` like this doesn't work anymore as you now also have to override the `getDatabaseName()` method. The property `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation` however does still work.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem when upgrading the spring boot version to 2.3.x and overriding this method on the config class solved it (what @yejianfengblue said above)

```
  @Override
  public boolean autoIndexCreation() {
    return true;
  }
```