# How to enforce unique field with MongoDB in Spring

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, unique-index

I have a pojo with two fields that need to be unique, the id and the email. So I added the `@Indexed(unique = true)` annotation to the necessary fields like so

```
public class User {
    @Id
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private int money;
```

I then tested it out and it was not enforced. So I googled about and I found a previous answer here - [Spring Data: Unique field in MongoDB document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385130/spring-data-unique-field-in-mongodb-document) and subsequently deleted the collection, added `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true` to my application.properties file and tried again.

However, the unique field still isn't enforced! I see there is another answer using `ensureIndex()` but it also has a great comment that was never answered- `Why do we need to use the annotation if all the work is done on mongoTemplate?`

So since the question is old enough that apparently the only working answer is depreciated (the new way is using `createIndex()`), I thought it was time for a new version. Is it possible to require a column in a mongo collection to be unique from Spring Boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the issue is fixed in the current latest spring boot data MongoDB version (v3.0.4).

I tested this on my own personal project using Spring Boot v3.0.4 with Java 17/Kotlin, my document class ended up like this:

```
@Document
class User(@Indexed(unique = true) var username: String) {

    @Id
    var id: String? = null

    var name: String? = null

    var surname: String? = null
}
```

Important: I did need to add `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true` to my application.properties file, only after doing this *and* dropping the collection on MongoDB I got the field actually enforced on my User API.

In my case, just after adding all of the above configurations (`@Indexed(unique=true)` and `spring.data.mongodb.auto-index-creation=true`), I started getting the following error when trying to insert a user with the same `username` as an existing one:

```
curl -v --location 'http://localhost:9000/user' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "testuser1",
    "name": "Test",
    "surname": "User 1"
}'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
> POST /user HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer <token>
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 76
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 409 
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 0
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Tue, 14 Mar 2023 18:48:08 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"cause":{"cause":null,"message":"Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.user index: username dup key: { username: \"testuser1\" }', details={}}."},"message":"Write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write error: WriteError{code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.user index: username dup key: { username: \"testuser1\" }', details={}}."}
```

Checking the DB for the records revealed that it indeed restricted and halted the write operation.

Other versions used on this test:

```
kotlin("jvm") - 1.7.22
kotlin("plugin.spring") - "1.7.22"

MongoDB - 4.4.10
Ubuntu (host) - 22.04
```